# Overlap in Set Theory

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Is this statement $$A \cap (B - C)  \subseteq A - (B \cap C)  $$ right? Where A, B, and C are  any three events. My initial guess was that $$A \cap (B - C)  = (A - B ) \cap (B - C)  $$. Any proof to show this statement is true?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this statement $A \cap (B \smallsetminus C)  \subseteq A \smallsetminus (B \cap C)  $ right?

The first includes elements that are in both A and B but not in C.  $A\cap (B\smallsetminus C) = A\cap B\cap C^\complement$

The second includes elements in A that are not in both B and C.  $A\smallsetminus (B\cap C) = A\cap (B^\complement\cup C^\complement)$

> Now $x\in A\cap B\cap C^\complement$ says $x$ is in $A$, in $B$, and not in $C$.   If it is not in $C$ we may infer it is not in both $B$ and $C$.   So $x\in A\cap(B\smallsetminus C)$ implies $x\in A\smallsetminus (B\cap C)$.

Therefore $A\cap(B\smallsetminus C) \subseteq A\smallsetminus (B\cap C)$

---

Your proposed equality however, is not so true.

Comment: So in effect i am proving this statement: $A\cap B\cap C^\complement \subseteq A\cap (B^\complement\cup C^\complement)$? Let $x $be in $A\cap B\cap C^\complement$. Then $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is in $B\cap C^\complement$. How then do I finish the proof?

Comment: @Lady See the spoiler section if it is not obvious, but note that  $x\in A\cap B\cap C^\complement \to x\in A\cap C^\complement$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a Venn Diagram with three sets and see if it is true.

Algebraically, you could write $B - C$ as $B \cap C^c$, $B$ intersected with the complement of $C$. The complement of $C$ can be interpretted as the set of all points in $A\cup B$ that are not in $C$ and then check to see if your first inequality is true. (Try to work it out.)

However, your equality is false:
$$A \cap (B-C) = A \cap (B \cap C^c) = A \cap B \cap C^c$$ and
$$(A- B) \cap (B-C) = (A \cap B^c)\cap (B \cap C^c) = A \cap B \cap B^c \cap C^c = \emptyset$$ because $B \cap B^c = \emptyset$. This makes sense because if you "read" what it is saying, it is saying that an element $x \in (A- B) \cap (B-C)$ is in $A$ but not $B$ and also in $B$ but not $C$, but that is not possible to be in $B$ and not in $B$.

This can all be checked using the standard "set theory" ideas of showing that a set is a subset of another by asking if an element of one set (that we want to show is the subset) is necessarily an element of the other set.